# BIOS setting to power on after power loss isn't working properly

Tags: boot, bios, uefi, power, firmware

What would make a PC to fail to automatically power on after power loss when it's configured to do it like that on the bios?

The PC works well otherwise and sometimes powers on automatically after the power loss, but usually, it doesn't.

EDIT with extra info:

There are in fact 3 different PC's on the same place. Two of them have a biostar 690GTA. The other one has a Gigabyte X299. The three PC are behaving in a similar way. They have debian installed but I don't think that matters.

To "simulate" a power loss I have tried both with the PSU switch and directly removing the power cable.

I don't know the BIOS versions and I don't have access to them right now (remote location), but if it's really necessary I can check.

Comment: Have you checked if there's a BIOS upgrade that might have a fix for an issue like this? Can you please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1767603/edit) your question and add the BIOS info - manufacturer, model, version?

Comment: What is the OS? Some, like Linux, might better handle an abrupt shutdown.

Comment: Done @Peregrino69

Comment: I intended to check whether there are applicable updates, but there are 17 different versions of X299 MoBo... [here's](https://www.gigabyte.com/Search?kw=X299#Products-2-1) the download page. Z690GTA page is [here](https://www.biostar.com.tw/app/en/mb/introduction.php?S_ID=1038) - hope this helps you further.

Answer (score -2):

If OS is Windows you may need additional step. Try:

- Open command prompt (admin)
- Type bcdedit /set {default} bootstatuspolicy ignoreshutdownfailures [enter]
- Should return "Operation completed successfully"

[image]